# Power bi tachometer visualizing the last value

Tags: powerbi

I send a json with random temperature to Power BI:

```
[
{
"CPU_Temp" :"12",
"CPU_TempMin" :0,
"CPU_TempMax" :100,
}
]
```

Then I want to display current CPU data in tachometer (custom Power BI visual)
I use `CPU_TempMin` for "Start Value", `CPU_TempMax` for "End Value", `CPU_Temp` for "Value".

I convert `CPU_Temp` to a string before sending it to get rid of aggregation on Power BI end (I don't need `SUM`, `AVG` etc) but it doesn't have an option for "Don't summarize".

I've checked all the gauges and neither of them has such an option.

Comment: Are you loading in a single row table with those values in three columns?

Answer (score 0):

Well,
I found the way to "avoid" aggregating functions.
Set all the values that you use(Start Value, End Value, Target Value etc) to AVG (average)
I need to add filter: drag into filters the CPU_Temp field
Than select Top N filter, type '1'
Drag Any Datetime field (you must have it in your JSON) to "By value", select Latest.

Eventually we display Average value calculate from 1 latest value, which is obviously equal to this latest value.